# SQL Server - Find similarities in column and write them into new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big table with data like this:

```
ID  Title
--  ------------------------
1   01_SOMESTRING_038
2   01_SOMESTRING K5038
3   01_SOMESTRING-648
4   K-OTHERSTRING_T_73474
5   K-OTHERSTRING_T_ffk
6   ABC
7   DEF
```

And the task is now to find similarities in that column, and write that found similarity to a new column.

So the desired output would be like this:

```
ID  Title                     Similarity
--  ------------------------  -----------------
1   01_SOMESTRING_038         01_SOMESTRING
2   01_SOMESTRING K5038       01_SOMESTRING
3   01_SOMESTRING-648         01_SOMESTRING
4   K-OTHERSTRING_T_73474     K-OTHERSTRING_T_
5   K-OTHERSTRING_T_ffk       K-OTHERSTRING_T_
6   ABC                       NULL
7   DEF                       NULL
```

How can I achieve that in MS SQL Server 17?
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** The strings are not only broken by delimiters such as "-", "_".
And for handling competeing similrities I would set a minimum length for the similarity. For instance 10.

Comment: How would yuo handle competing similarities, for example of row 3 was `01-SOMEOTHER' would it be the only row with that in the Similarity?

Comment: And is it only broken by delimiters such as dash, space, underscore or is "THISISONE-123" similar to "THISISTWO-456" up to "THISIS"?

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not only broken by delimiters. Yes, "THISISONE-123" would be similar to "THISISTWO-456" up to "THISIS"

Comment: Thats a good question, what to do with competeing similrities. May I would set a minimum length for similarity, as all my data have a specific lenght for the similarity. For instance I would set this to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, using a recursive CTE to split out the letters, then we can group them up to find the greatest match:

```
WITH TITLE_EXPAND AS (
    SELECT
        1 MatchLen
        ,CAST(SUBSTRING(Title,1,1) as NVARCHAR(255)) MatchString
        ,Title
        ,ID
    FROM
        [SourceDataTable]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        MatchLen + 1
        ,CAST(SUBSTRING(Title,1,MatchLen+1) AS NVARCHAR(255))
        ,Title
        ,ID     
    FROM 
        TITLE_EXPAND
    WHERE 
        MatchLen < LEN(Title)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    SDT.ID
    ,SDT.title
    ,FIRST_VALUE(MatchString) OVER (PARTITION BY SDT.ID ORDER BY SC.MatchLen DESC, SC.MatchCount DESC) Similarity
FROM
    [SourceDataTable] SDT
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        *
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MatchString, MatchLen) MatchCount
    FROM 
        TITLE_EXPAND) SC
ON
    SDT.ID = SC.ID
    AND
    SC.MatchCount > 1
ORDER BY SDT.ID
```

Where SourceDataTable is your source table.  The Similarity value will be the longest matched similar value.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. How can I add the result to my old table?

Comment: You can just update your old table based on the above, linking via the ID field

Comment: I just have still one problem: Your code gives the longest matched value: But if I have something like this: ABCDE1** (100 times), ABCDE11173** (50 times), it matches ABCDE1 as similarity and also ABCDE11173 as similarity, but I'd only like to have ABCDE1 as similarity (150 times). So I don't want the longest possible match, but the match with the highest match count for every "group"

Comment: If you switch the order by round on the FIRST_VALUE from `SC.MatchLen DESC, SC.MatchCount DESC` to `SC.MatchCount DESC, SC.MatchLen DESC` it'll give you the highest match count instead

Comment: Thanks, Matt! Can I also only get Similarities that have a minimum length with 10 characters for instance? Because all my strings are starting with the same prefix... and by using the highest match count, it always uses the Prefix.

Comment: Yeah, if you change the lines at the top from `1 MatchLen` and `SUBSTRING(Title,1,1)` to `10 MatchLen` and `SUBSTRING(Title,1,10)`